# Pandas acting weird when using dataframe.shift()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading in some data which looks like this:

[image: Original data]

In this dataset, a number of rows have `null` in column 16. I need to shift the values in such rows to the right, so that the values which begin with "*" (eg. column 16 row 4, column 13 row 5 etc.) will move to the columns right of them. **(Eventually I will do this in a loop so that those values will go into column 16)** .

**The data to the left of these values also have to move too. For example when the data in {column 7 row 16} moves to {column 8, row 16}, the data in {column 2  row 16} should move to {column 3 row 16}.**

**However, I do not want the data in column 1 (zero index column 0) to move as I will be using that as an index for my data.**

Hence my expected output is this:

[image: Expected output after iteration 1]

I am using the code below to achieve this:

```
import StringIO
import pandas

# Store the csv string in a variable and turn that into a dataframe
# This string here is the same as the data in the image above.
gps_string = """2010-01-12 18:00:00,$GPGGA,180439,7249.2150,N,11754.4238,W,2.0,10,0.9,-8.1,M,-12.4,M,,*57,,,
2010-01-12 17:30:00,$GPGGA,173439,7249.2160,N,11754.4233,W,2.0,11,0.8,-4.5,M,-12.4,M,,*5B,,,
2010-01-12 17:00:00,$GPGGA,170439,7249.2152,N,11754.4235,W,2.0,11,0.8,-3.1,M,-12.4,M,,*5C,,,
2010-01-12 16:30:00,N,11754.4210,W,2,9.0,1.1,-13.1,M,-12.4,M,,*6C,,,,,,
2010-01-12 16:00:00,N,11754.4229,W,2,10.0,0.9,-2.9,M,-12.4,M,,*53,,,,,,
2010-01-12 15:30:00,N,11754.4269,W,2,9.0,0.8,-4.3,M,-12.4,M,,*54,,,,,,
2010-01-12 15:00:00,N,11754.4267,W,2,10.0,0.8,-1.6,M,-12.4,M,,*56,,,,,,
2010-01-12 14:30:00,$GPGGA,143439,7249.2152,N,11754.4253,W,2.0,11,0.7,-4.3,M,-12.4,M,,*56,,,
2010-01-12 14:00:00,N,11754.4245,W,2,10.0,0.9,-7.0,M,-12.4,M,,*50,,,,,,
2010-01-12 13:30:00,$GPGGA,133439,7249.2134,N,11754.4243,W,2.0,11,0.7,-10.7,M,-12.4,M,,*61,,,
2010-01-12 13:00:00,N,11754.4245,W,2,10.0,0.8,-5.5,M,-12.4,M,,*56,,,,,,
2010-01-12 12:30:00,N,11754.4226,W,2,10.0,0.9,-7.1,M,-12.4,M,,*59,,,,,,
2010-01-12 12:00:00,N,11754.4238,W,2,10.0,0.8,-6.5,M,-12.4,M,,*51,,,,,,
2010-01-12 11:30:00,N,11754.4227,W,2,10.0,0.8,0.1,M,-12.4,M,,*73,,,,,,
2010-01-12 11:00:00,-7.4,M,-12.4,M,,*5F,,,,,,,,,,,,
2010-01-12 10:30:00,N,11754.4271,W,2,8.0,1.1,-8.4,M,-12.4,M,,*5A,,,,,,
""" 
# Read the csv string into a dataframe, with no headers
# Make the first column with timestamp values the index column.
gps_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(gps_string), header=None, 
index_col=0)
rows_to_shift = gps_df[gps_df[15].isnull()].index

# Shift the rows here.
gps_df.loc[rows_to_shift] = gps_df.loc[rows_to_shift].shift(periods=1, axis=1)
gps_df.to_csv("f.csv") # Creates a file after shift to see the output
```

I get the following output file when the code is executed.

[image: Output after Execution]

From this I see that the shift function creates a column of `null(s)` at column 5 for some reason, and it also moves the data that was originally in column 10 into column 15, any idea why this might be the case?

Could this be a bug in the `dataframe.shift()` function? or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide some data as text rather than as pictures so people could test and compare solutions to what you've tried

Comment: @G.Anderson, I have added some test data to the question as requested

Comment: Please see [how to create good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and show both your sample input and desired output, as your problem description is confusing

Comment: @G.Anderson I've made some edits to the question, is it better now?

Comment: I'm also seeing some very weird behavior with `.shift()` in my testing, trying to figure it out on my end as well. It seems to reorder text columns when applied along axis 1

Comment: @G.Anderson Same issue I'm dealing with, it moves one of my columns (column 10) to column 15

Comment: @G.Anderson Its a bug from pandas I've opened an issue here https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26929 you can follow it for updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in pandas, and more details can be found [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26929) .

it seems that shifting object columns will automatically shift to the next column that has an object dtype.

In order to work around this issue, I select the indexes I want to shift, convert all the data in my dataframe to strings, perform the shift, get the data as a csv string again, and then recreate the dataframe to get the previous datatypes.

Below is the code I have used to work around this issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import StringIO

gps_string = """
"2010-01-12 18:00:00","$GPGGA","180439","7249.2150","N","11754.4238","W","2","10","0.9","-8.1","M","-12.4","M","","*57","","",""
"2010-01-12 17:30:00","$GPGGA","173439","7249.2160","N","11754.4233","W","2","11","0.8","-4.5","M","-12.4","M","","*5B","","",""
"2010-01-12 17:00:00","$GPGGA","170439","7249.2152","N","11754.4235","W","2","11","0.8","-3.1","M","-12.4","M","","*5C","","",""
"2010-01-12 16:30:00","N","11754.4210","W","2","09","1.1","-13.1","M","-12.4","M","","*6C","","","","","",""
"2010-01-12 16:00:00","N","11754.4229","W","2","10","0.9","-2.9","M","-12.4","M","","*53","","","","","",""
"2010-01-12 15:30:00","N","11754.4269","W","2","09","0.8","-4.3","M","-12.4","M","","*54","","","","","",""
"2010-01-12 15:00:00","N","11754.4267","W","2","10","0.8","-1.6","M","-12.4","M","","*56","","","","","",""
"2010-01-12 14:30:00","$GPGGA","143439","7249.2152","N","11754.4253","W","2","11","0.7","-4.3","M","-12.4","M","","*56","","",""
"2010-01-12 14:00:00","N","11754.4245","W","2","10","0.9","-7.0","M","-12.4","M","","*50","","","","","",""
"2010-01-12 13:30:00","$GPGGA","133439","7249.2134","N","11754.4243","W","2","11","0.7","-10.7","M","-12.4","M","","*61","","",""
"2010-01-12 13:00:00","N","11754.4245","W","2","10","0.8","-5.5","M","-12.4","M","","*56","","","","","",""
"2010-01-12 12:30:00","N","11754.4226","W","2","10","0.9","-7.1","M","-12.4","M","","*59","","","","","",""
"2010-01-12 12:00:00","N","11754.4238","W","2","10","0.8","-6.5","M","-12.4","M","","*51","","","","","",""
"2010-01-12 11:30:00","N","11754.4227","W","2","10","0.8","0.1","M","-12.4","M","","*73","","","","","",""
"2010-01-12 11:00:00","-7.4","M","-12.4","M","","*5F","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"2010-01-12 10:30:00","N","11754.4271","W","2","08","1.1","-8.4","M","-12.4","M","","*5A","","","","","",""

 """

gps_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(gps_string), header=None, index_col=0)
rows_to_shift = gps_df[gps_df[15].isnull()].index  # get the indexes to shift
gps_df_all_strings = gps_df.astype(str)  # Convert all the data to be of type str (string)

# Shift the data
gps_df_all_strings.loc[rows_to_shift] = gps_df_all_strings.loc[rows_to_shift].shift(periods=1, axis=1)
s = gps_df_all_strings.to_csv(header=None)  # Put shifted csv data into a string after shifting.
new_gps_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(s), header=None, index_col=0)  # re read csv data.
```